# How to vertically align icon and text in React?

Tags: css, reactjs

https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-g5pez?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

[image]

```
<span>
    {

        item.result.map((item, idx) => {
            return <span className="legend-label">
                <StopIcon />{item.metric}: {item.count}</span>
        })
    }
</span>
```

I am rendering `material-icon` and putting a text next to it. However, I am not sure how to make them vertically align with the RIGHT practice. Of course, I can put `top` or `bottom` attribute to style to make a tweak, but I believe that is not the right practice of doing this.

What is the right way to do this without generating a bad aftermath?

Comment: You can use `flex` or adjust the `line-height`, I believe alignment has nothing to do if it's `React` or not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-u71qr

Just add some style to the `legend-label`:

```css
display: inline-flex;
align-items: center;
```

Answer (score 1):

Making use of css flex is one option:

```
<span style={{ display:'inline-flex', alignItems: 'center' }} className="legend-label">
  <StopIcon style={{ color: palette[idx] }} />
  {item.metric}: {item.count}
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     <span>
        {objarr.map((item, idx) => {
          return (
            <span style={{display:'flex', alignItems:'center'}} className="legend-label">
              <StopIcon style={{ color: palette[idx] }} />
              {item.metric}: {item.count}
            </span>
          );
        })}
      </span>
```

Comment: applying `flex` alone doesn't have any effect. Have you tested it?